# CGI::unescape giving error undefined method `tr'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, escaping, cgi

I am trying to execute this line of code

```
key_inside = CGI::unescape(key)
val_inside = CGI::unescape(val)
```

and its giving me error like

```
undefined method `tr' for :oauth_consumer_key:Symbol\n
```

I am using Rails 2.3.18 and ruby 1.9.3

Can any one please suggest as to what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error indicates that some code somewhere is expecting a String but it is getting a Symbol, and when it calls `.tr()` on the Symbol, it produces the error.  Try:

```
key_inside = CGI::unescape(key.to_s)
```

Comment: Thanks let me give it a try

Comment: Thank you for that.